# What hubs to use for USB 3.1 gen 1?

Tags: usb, hub, display-port

I bought a laptop (ASUS VivoBook Pro 15 N580VD) that comes with a USB type C 3.1 GEN 1 port, that is also a displayport port (little DP icon - like the one in [this picture](https://www.displayport.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/devices-stack.jpg))

I would like to buy a hub with an ethernet port, (at least) 2 displayports/HDMIs, at least one USB type A and at least one USB type c port.
I am concerned that a hub like this won't work since the laptop has a gen 1 port.

What USB 3.1 Gen 1 hubs would work for my laptop?

Comment: Can you tell us what you would like to use this hub for exactly? As it is written it is a little hard to follow. Also, can you list the exact laptop that you have please.

Comment: Laptop is ASUS VivoBook Pro 15 N580VD.
I would like to have as little cables as possible. So if it's possible, I would buy a hub with ethernet port, (at least) 2 displayports/HDMIs, at least one USB type A and at least one USB type c port. IF it would work on usb 3.1 gen 1. I know this would work on gen 2, but I'm not sure about gen 1.

Comment: I have edited your question to include the information from your comment. Please add anything that I may have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 years later when I got a dock for different laptop I remembered this and tested.
So USB C 3.1 gen 1 port (now named USB 3.2 gen 1) using powered HP Universal Dock connected to:

- 1080p 60hz monitor with displayport -> HDMI adapter
- Ultrawide 1440p monitor up to 100Hz (monitor capable 144hz) with displayport cable
- 2 usb dongles for wireless mouse and keyboard
- usb sound card with 5.1 speakers plugged
- ethernet 1Gbps cable

Everything except bigger monitor is working fully, that UW monitor working well enough